# Write a java program that reads an integer number made up of 4 digits, and prints the number in reverse

Tags: java, c++, netbeans

Write a java program that reads (you must read it as an integer) an integer number made up of 4 digits, and prints the number in reverse order. For example if the number read is 7134 then your program will print 4317. (Hint use % and integer division).

ANSWER -->

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n;
    int reverse1;
    int reverse2;
    int reverse3;
    int reverse4;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number made up of 4 digits : ");
    n = s.nextInt();

    reverse1 = (((n % 1000) % 100) % 10);
    reverse2 = (((n % 1000) % 100) / 10);
    reverse3 = ((n % 1000) / 100);
    reverse4 = ((n / 1000));

    System.out.print("The number in reverse order : ");
    System.out.print(reverse1);
    System.out.print(reverse2);
    System.out.print(reverse3);
    System.out.print(reverse4);
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: It works, but you can simplify it a bit. For example `reverse1 = n % 10;`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what the issue is, but would find this a prettier solution:

```
while (n > 0) {
    System.out.print(n%10);
    n /= 10;
}
```

It would work for an integer of any length.

Comment: this is the question and i answer it , it can read number in reverse order